# Show that $f(n) = \gcd(a,n)$ is a multiplicative function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, multiplicative-function

I want to show that $f(n) = \gcd(a,n)$ where **a** is any natural number, is a [multiplicative function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).

I know I need to show that $f(mn)=f(n)*f(m)$, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: No, you need to show $f(mn) = f(n) f(m)$ when $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes **your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it.** This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Note that with the common number-theoretic sense of "multiplicative function" you're only supposed to show this when $m$ and $n$ are coprime. (And otherwise it isn't true, anyway). The Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic will be handy.

Comment: In this context, an asterisk ($*$) (the Dirichlet's convolution) is far from a synonym of a dot ($\cdot$) (the usual product).

Comment: @Stella  Robotic, pre-formatted comments are just that, and rarely taken as anything but. Auto-commenting gets old, fast.

Comment: @amWhy But it is still much better than leaving the post without an explanation for putting on-hold. And, of course, if you think that there is something which needs to be added to the above comment, you can go ahead and write another comment.

Comment: A handful of duplicates [found using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cgcd(ab%2Cc)%3D%5Cgcd(a%2Cc)%5Cgcd(b%2Cc)%24%2C%20%24%5Cgcd(a%2Cb)%3D1%24&p=1):
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536554/gcdab-c-equals-gcda-c-times-gcd-b-c
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535961/prove-that-if-gcda-b-1-then-gcda-cdot-b-c-gcda-c-cdot-gcdb-c
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806096/let-a-m-n-in-mathbfn-show-that-if-gcdm-n-1-then-gcda-mn-gcda
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846522/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdab-c-gcda-c-cdot-gcdb-c

Comment: Are you trying to show that it is [multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function) or [completely multiplicative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_multiplicative_function)? I guess you left out the condition that $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Answer (score 5):

If you prove that
$$ \gcd(a,x) = \prod_{p\mid a} p^{\min(\nu_p(a),\nu_p(x))} $$
where $\nu_p(x)=\max\{m\in\mathbb{N}: p^m\mid x\}$ the question becomes trivial. If $x$ and $y$ are coprime integers they have no common prime factor, so
$$ \gcd(a,xy) = \prod_{p\mid a}p^{\min(\nu_p(a),\nu_p(xy))}=\prod_{p\mid x\,\wedge\, p|a}p^{\min(\nu_p(a),\nu_p(xy))}\prod_{p\mid y\,\wedge\, p|a}p^{\min(\nu_p(a),\nu_p(xy))} $$
and the RHS equals
$$ \prod_{p\mid x\,\wedge\, p|a}p^{\min(\nu_p(a),\nu_p(x))}\prod_{p\mid y\,\wedge\, p|a}p^{\min(\nu_p(a),\nu_p(y))}=\gcd(a,x)\gcd(a,y). $$