# Property of addition, multiplication of $\gcd$ for co-prime $(a,b)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Need the use of property of addition and subtraction of $\gcd$ for my approach to prove :

 $(a,b)=1\implies (ab, a+b)=1$

My approach:
$(a,b)=1\implies (ab,b^2)=b$
$(a,b)=1\implies (ab,a^2)=a$

$((ab,b^2)=b\wedge (ab,a^2)=a)\implies (2ab,a^2+b^2)=b+a\implies (2ab,a^2+b^2+2ab) = a+b \implies (2ab,(a+b)^2) = a+b$

Need help to proceed further, if correct.

Comment: The implication $((ab,b^2)=b∧(ab,a^2)=a)⟹(2ab,a^2+b^2) = b+a$ doesn't hold in general... I think it almost never holds actually.

Comment: @mike239x Please provide details for the cause of invalidity of the addition operation on $\gcd$.

Comment: OK, underlying you have that from $x | y$ and $s | t$ you can't conclude that $x+s\ |\ y + t$. And now you'll ask the cause for that, I assume.

Comment: @mike239x Please tell the reason.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to say. It just breaks way too easy. For example you take $y = 0$ and (since all numbers divide zero) you get that all numbers divide $t$...

Comment: @mike239x Thanks, but then it points to invalidity of division of linear combinations too. Anyway, the explanation is too simple and is very much valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint :

- if $(a,b)=1$, then $(c, ab) = (c,a)\times (c,b)$
- $(a,b) = (a+b, b)$

Note that you can't "add" gcds so easily. E.g : $(2,6) = 2$ and $(1,4) = 1$ but $(3, 10) = 1$

Comment: Then it is very simple one, I hope. It is also the one I wanted avoid, if am correct. It is hopefully: $(a,a+b)=(b,a+b)=1$, taking product, get: $(ab, a+b) = 1$. I wanted to clear up on sum and product of $\gcd$, so wanted another approach. I am still not clear why sum is not valid, when product is. If some logical reasoning were provided kindly, then would serve the purpose a lot.

Comment: Right. Note that this is only simple because you asked for properties of the gcd. Now you might wonder why do those properties hold...

Comment: Yes, that is the key to understanding why one operation(*) holds, but not the other(+), on $\gcd$. I would be waiting for your response on that, as it seems too crucial to understanding of $\gcd$.

Comment: I'd suggest you try a little bit on your own to prove those properties. Second one is easy, first one can be tough. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846522/if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdab-c-gcda-c-cdot-gcdb-c) if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but regarding the invalidity of sum operation on $\gcd$ request some help too. The link provided is for product operation only.

Comment: I'm not sure what help you're looking for ? It's simply not true, as shown in the counterexample in my answer.