# Proving If and only if gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,c) = 1, then gcd(ab,c) = 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have tried to show this using the proposition that if gcd(a,b)=1, there exists two integers, x and y, such that $1 = ax + by$.

I first tried to prove the implication starting with gcd(a,b) = gcd(b,c) = 1.

$1 = ax + by$
and
$1 = bk + cm$

I then tried to manipulate these to the form
$1 = abl + cj$
(with l and j being integers)

I ran into trouble with multiplying by 1 in various places and replacing by either of the above identites because b is alone and both, so I kept on ending up with factors of b that I couldn't get rid of.

I also tried using the definition of gcd(a,b) = d, such that
$i) d > -1$  .
$ii)$ *d divides both a and b.*
$iii)$ *any divisor of both a and b also divides d.*

I got equally stuck using this method.

Comment: I was thinking about why $d>-1$?

Comment: Since d is an integer, this is equivalent to saying d is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: But gcd cannot be zero right?

Comment: This may help- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/536179/prove-that-if-gcda-b-1-then-gcdab-c-gcda-c-gcdb-c

Comment: @IsaacSpivack Is it $GCD(a,c)$ or $GCD(a,b)$?

Comment: @KeyFlex the gcd(a,b) is not a typo and is intentional, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COUNTEREXAMPLE!

You cannot prove the title statement, it is false

Your title condition can be satisfied with $a=c,$ as long as the gcd with $b$ is one.

$$ a = 5,b=6, c = 5 $$

Then $$ \gcd(a,b) = 1$$
$$ \gcd(b,c) = 1$$

BUT
$$ \gcd(ab,c) = \gcd(30,5) = 5  $$

Comment: Wouldn't this be proving just a specific case of the statement?

Comment: How the title condition is satisfied, even we put an extra condition $a=c$, still gcd of ab and c is not 1

Comment: Ah, I understand. So even though my book asks to prove this statement (doesn't ask to identify if it is true and then prove, so I assumed it was) it isn't true. I'll e-mail my professor about that then I suppose. Thanks!