# $\gcd(ab,c)$ equals $\gcd(a,c)$ times $\gcd( b, c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Let $a,b,c$ be integers, prove that if $\gcd(a,b) =1$ then
$\gcd(ab,c) = \gcd(a,c)\times\gcd(b,c)$

I don't know what to do after I got the combinations of $ab$ and $c$.

Comment: Hint: show $gcd(ab, c) | gcd(a, c)*gcd(b, c)$ and $gcd(a, c)*gcd(b, c) | gcd(ab, c)$.

Comment: I know we can show that (a,c)(b,c) divides (ab,c) by gcd-ct

Comment: but how do I show gcd (ab,c) divides (a,c) and (b,c)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535961/prove-that-if-gcda-b-1-then-gcda-cdot-b-c-gcda-c-cdot-gcdb-c

Answer (score 4):

My favorite way to think about gcd's is in terms of multisets.  Using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic there is a bijection from every positive integer to multisets of primes.  For example, $12 = \{2,2,3\}, 49 = \{7,7\}$, and so on.  Also let $1 = \emptyset$, the empty set.  Then GCD's can then be looked at as the intersection of multisets. Multiplying numbers amounts to taking unions of multisets, and so on.  It's $1$ if the intersection is empty.  Then you can instantly see things like the fact you're proving by using set theory.  In particular, if $M_a, M_b, M_c$ correspond to the multisets for $a,b,c$, then your fact amounts to showing that if $M_a \cap M_b = \emptyset$, then $(M_a \cup M_b) \cap M_c = (M_a \cap M_c) \cup (M_a \cap M_b)$, which is a standard result from an elementary proofs course! Hope that helps.